# How can I reset Physics for fluid simulation?

Tags: physics, fluid-simulation

I created a water simulation, added a cube as domain and applied collision to the ground. It didnt work, the water just went through. So, I decided then to apply Boolean to the cube domain that way it could get the shape of the ground and avoid to apply another collision object. The simulation just baked as it were a cube, it didn't follow the shape after Boolean. the water it's just passing through as shown in the picture.
[image]

I have tried different ways but can't get to reset the water simulation and follow the shape of the ground.

I never hit the bake button but it seems to be saved somewhere. How can I reset previous bake of water simulation?

Answer (score 2):

1. Regular physics Collision has no effect on liquids. If you are using correct Fluid Collision, check that the normals are the right way on your plane.
2. Because the mesh of a fluid domain is actually completely replaced by the mesh generated by the simulation, the domain itself always must be cuboidal and aligned with the world axes and will thus will automatically be a bounding box of whatever mesh the domain was originally,
3. To clear the cache of a fluid domain: Seek to scene frame 1, then force the fluid cache to delete by changing the domain resolution, then change it back. The cache will reset unless you baked it.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works now. Just a think more please, in my view port looks like it should look, a water stream but after render I just get a giant cube with water texture. What am I missing to get the water rendered as it looks in viewport?

Comment: @NATURUNATURYU That is a separate question, but basically you need to enable Mesh in the domain fluid settings.

Comment: You are right. Will make a new question but thank you very much for your help.